# Did Superboy [Conner Kent] and Batgirl [Cassandra Cain] ever date?

Tags: comics, batgirl, superboy

I was checking my scans for some particular information and happened across this:

[image]

It struck me as new, and oddly intimate. I wasn't even aware Conner *knew* Cassie.

Last I read, connor had died fighting Superboy Prime, and he had been dating Wonder Girl at the time. Robin [his best friend] and Wonder girl eventually found some kind of solace about his death with each other. But this is the first time I've seen them together.

IS this a flirtation, or just a special moment with no romantic undertones?

And did this happen before or after Conner's death?

Comment: "did this happen before or after Conner's death?" <sigh/>  Thank you for reminding me why I've (mostly) given up reading comics...

Comment: I'm having a real hard time processing the fact that someone called Orphan a "Bat-babe" and got away with it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's part of [Batgirl Vol 1 41](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Batgirl_Vol_1_41)

They kiss a few times too but later decided to be just friends.

[Arousinggrammar](https://arousinggrammar.com/page/46/) also show the full story with comic pages.

Comment: Thank you. So just another  _Young Heroes in Love_ or "shipping Harley Quinn Around" kinda story, then...nice.

Comment: You know, it occurs to me, that at this point, Tim Drake can hear Connor call out **"Cassssie!"** and wonder "Why did you say that name!?" only for Aqualad to rush in and say "It's his girlfriends name! she needs help!" only to see Tim run off to save _Wonder Girl,_ who is sitting there like "Dude, I'm fine...."  meanwhile, _Bat girl_ is getting her ass handed to her by Lady Shiva!