# What was the first retconned superhero origin story?

Tags: comics, history-of, super-hero, retcon

Inspired by [this question.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/222683/1253) The “Superboy” in that question not only isn’t the “original”, his origin story even as the “new” Superboy has apparently changed multiple times.

There was a time when comic character bios were seemingly set in stone.  Sure, we’d have the occasional “imaginary tale,” but in general the modern practice of constantly reinventing origin stories and renaming secret identities was unheard of. I’m interested to learn who first decided that this was a thing. What was the first time in comics that a superhero got a completely rewritten origin story?

Comment: I have my doubts that it's the first one, but in the 1960s, Superman's powers were retconned from being the product of good genetics and originating from a high-gravity world to being empowered by Earth's yellow sun.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots It wouldn't surprise me if it was the first after all. Continuity was not an important principle in the superhero genre at that time.

Comment: I sure wish I could call Sherlock Holmes a "superhero": https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/retcon-history-and-meaning

Comment: I am not sure this counts. Both explanations boil down to “he has superpowers because he’s an alien from Krypton.”  If he started out being a gorilla-human hybrid and then was changed into an alien, that would count!

Comment: @Ernest Then you're going to have to provide a concrete example (I.e. an actual superhero retcon) that meets your criteria. Retconning is more for "oops we screwed up, now we have to make the story consistent" than it is "let's make up something entirely different just for the heck of it".

Comment: @Spencer Added a link to my question to provide some context.

Comment: Possibly the Silver Age Flash (Barry Allen)who premiered in Showcase #4 (October 1956).  The "original" Flash was the "Golden Age" Flash (Jay Garrick).  Or was this not what you had in mind?

Comment: Probably not the first, but when Jim Starlin introduced the race of titans (from Saturn's moon Titan), they were an offshoot of the Greek gods of the Marvel Universe (Hercules, etc.). During the 1980s, this was retconned to them being an offshoot of The Eternals. This retcon affected heroes like Mentor and Eros/Starfox.

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt I think that’s exactly what I had in mind!

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill But that's not an example of a hero who "got a completely rewritten origin story", it's a completely different hero who just happens to share the same name because the second character had read about the first in comic books.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but rather broad for this venue. Maybe it would be better to edit the question to ask when and how _Superboy's_ origin story changed, and then, in a separate question, ask if any other superhero's origin story was changed earlier. (I would not be surprised if Superboy's was the first.)

Comment: Yeah. That's not a retcon at all. "Retcon" is short for "retroactive continuity". As has been pointed out, there having been more than one character called The Flash has nothing to do with retroactive continuity. -1 for the question

Comment: A few years before the 'new' Superboy appeared, the second Robin (Jason Todd) was given a completely new origin as a result of the Crisis on Infinite Earths event. Prior to this his origin was a carbon copy of the first Robin (Dick Grayson) - a circus performer whose parents were murdered. Post-Crisis he was a street kid whom Batman actually found in the process of stealing the wheels off the Batmobile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the OP indicated in comments that this was what he had in mind, I'm giving it as an actual answer.  Possibly the Silver Age Flash (Barry Allen)who premiered in Showcase #4 (October 1956). The "original" Flash was the "Golden Age" Flash (Jay Garrick).

Comment: Barry Flash also had a bit of a ret-con on his own origin when the accident that caused his power was attributed to a mystical being called "Mopee", kind of a "Bat-Mite" sort of character.  Fans were not amused. https://comiccoverage.typepad.com/comic_coverage/2009/02/the-real-idiotic-origin-of-the-flash.html

Answer (score 4):

Probably 1939, when "a passing motorist" 
http://www.comicbookreligion.com/?c=18225&unnamed_orphanage_attendants
became "Mary Kent" 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_and_Martha_Kent

Answer (score 3):

When [The Shadow](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Shadow) debuted in pulp magazines in 1931, he was aviator Kent Allard, and he blackmailed Lamont Cranston into allowing Kent to assume his legal identity. When the radio series debuted in 1937, The Shadow was Lamont Cranston with no separate original identity.